# Number Literals in Java

Tags: java, literals

When would an assignment not be an integer literal. I understand that `int a = 5;` is, but would `int a = b + c;` also be an integer literal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: .................no.

Comment: so the first one is, the second one isnt?

Comment: ..............correct.

Comment: Literals are literal numbers or strings, not variables or operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When would an assignment not be an integer literal.

An assignment is NEVER a literal.

> I understand that `int a = 5;` is

Actually, it isn't.  The literal is `5`.

The whole lot is a *declaration*, and the stuff on the right hand of the `=` is an *expression* (that is just literal in this case).

<sup>(And technically speaking, `int a = 5;` is not an assignment ... though it certainly includes an "assignment" in the form of the initialization.)</sup>

> but would `int a = b + c;` also be an integer literal.

No it isn't.

Once again, this is a declaration, and the stuff on the the right hand of the `=` is an expression.  But in this case the expression isn't a literal, and doesn't even involve a literal.

A literal is a syntactic element that represents a single definite value.  Here are some examples:

- `5` - a integer literal
- `5.0` - a double literal
- `'X'` - a character literal
- `"Hi mum"` - a string literal
- `false` - a boolean literal
- `String.class` - a class literal

By contrast `b` and `c` are the names of variables, which could *contain* different values ... at different points in the program's execution.  Variable names are not literals.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the refresher. "XX is not a literal" sounds almost comical :)